# Google map not showing in div

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I have a Google map div that shows when I define the height in pixels but not as a percentage; in my examples I try setting the height to 100%.

I have read a few SOF answers that suggest the parent div heights must also be set which I have done by targeting all of the map's parent divs in css as you can see, but the map does not show. Can anyone help?

Here is my code that **does** work:

```
            <div id="map-wrapper">
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
```

```
html, body, #map-wrapper #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 840px;
    width: 100%;  }
```

Here is my code that does **not** work:

```
            <div id="map-wrapper">
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
```

```
html, body, #map-wrapper #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  }
```

**JavaScript**:

```
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: also post ur javascript

Comment: I know that there are multipe issues with css and height 100% sometimes it is related with the size of the partent element. Please setup a jsfiddle with your actual code (if possible, if not create a simple colored div based example)

Comment: As I explained I have targeted all of the parent divs with the css?

Comment: [This simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/e1gj6tLo/) works as intended (I just not add a valid key).

Comment: I do not want the height defined in pixels like your example - I want it as a percentage

Comment: My fault I copied the wrong css, you need to set the height to all divs: http://jsfiddle.net/e1gj6tLo/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that for a height of 100% you need to set all parent elements also to 100% height.

In [my fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/e1gj6tLo/2/)<sup>1</sup> the map is at html -> body -> div#map-wrapper -> div#map-canvas. Each element must have the height 100%.

So basically I just added that map-wrapper div to your css:

```
html, body, #map-wrapper, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Your existing css with `#map-wrapper #map-canvas` (notice the missing comma!) would leave out the surrounding div.

<sup>1</sup> I added no api key so you get an error alert, and for debugging I gave the map a red background.

Comment: You helped me realise I was missing commas to delimit the IDs in my css, thanks